# Pass config block from a macro to create incremental model in DBT - Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I have around 200 tables which I need to load using merge incremental model in DBT-Bigquery. I was trying to create a macro which can take the input of source table name , target table name & Unique key and it can generate the incremental model. Macro code below :

```
{% macro generate_merge_incremental_model_sql(target_table,primary_key,work_table) %}


{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='{{primary_key}} ',
        incremental_strategy = 'merge',
        alias="{{ target_table }}"
    )
}}

select * from 
{{ source('source_data', 'customer_nonpart') }}

{% endmacro %}
```

But it is failing with compilation error while I am calling the code as below :

```
        {{
            generate_merge_incremental_model_sql(
                "customer_different_name", "customer_id", "customer_nonpart1"
            )
        }}
```

It is not able to evaluate the target_table parameter. I am not sure if I this is the right approach as I think the Config values is not parsing properly from Macro.